# How Do I Add 15 Minutes To A Datetime In Ruby Only Between Certain Hours Of The Day?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3.1

I'm a full time SQL Server database developer, but I'm looking to start utilizing Ruby for certain management tasks.  Also, I'm trying to take my Rails skills to the next level.  I'm great with SQL, but weak in programming languages (I'm working hard to fix that!).  Here is my question:

I want to write a simple loop that will seed my database for a rails application for an appointments model.  I want to start with a Monday date (let's say March 19, 2012) and I want to end with a Friday date (March 23, 2012).  I want to start at 9am on each day, and I want to end at 5pm each day.  I want my appointments in 15 minute intervals.

Currently, I have a simple loop that will add the 15 minutes to a parsed time.  However, I want to add 15 minutes only between the hours of 9am and 5pm each day.  Here is my code so far:

```
s = Time.parse("March 19, 2012, 9:00 AM")
e = Time.parse("March 23, 2012 5:00 PM") + 15 * 60

while s < e
  puts "#{s} "
  s+=15 * 60
end
```

I have a perfect list of dates from the above code (although I know there's probably a much better way to do it), but as I said, I want to limit my results so that I don't seed my database table with a bunch of useless dates that I constantly have to deal with in my Rails application.

Any advice would be greatly appreciated.  Thank you in advance for your help!

Comment: Wouldn't it be better to just have a list of the 15 minute increments between 9AM and 5PM? When the user selects 10AM, the system would take the 60 minutes from the list and then set the time there? How many days are you looking at adding? It doesn't sound like you need to populate a table with a list of 15 minute increments.

Comment: Your code sets and then ignores `s`. A better description of what you're trying to accomplish would help.

Comment: Whoops...a typo on my part.  Does this help clarify things?

Comment: I see your point, kobaltz, and I agree.  But, unless I'm missing something (and I may be), I still have to create the list whether I store it in the database or not.  So, I think it's the same problem, is it not?  I'm totally open here, so feel free to correct me :) Oh, and I'm looking to create dates for one specific week, Monday through Friday, 9am to 5pm each day.  Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I'd do it like this...

```
Appointment.delete_all # clear table

start_date = Time.parse("March 19, 2012, 9:00 AM")
end_date = Time.parse("March 23, 2012 5:00 PM")

# create a range from start_date to end_date moving in 15 minute intervals
(start_date..end_date).step(15 * 60) do |date_time|
  # only create Appointment if the hour is in the range 9 - 17 (24 hour clock)
  Appointment.create(:appt => date_time) if (9..17) === date_time.hour
end
```

**Alternate version for ruby 1.9.3**

```
curr_time = start_date
begin
  Appointment.create(:appt => curr_time) if (9..17) === curr_time.hour     
end while (curr_time += 60 * 15) <= end_date
```

**EDIT:** This works for me.

```
irb(main):003:0> require 'time'
=> true
irb(main):004:0> start_date = Time.parse("March 19, 2012, 9:00 AM")
=> Mon Mar 19 09:00:00 -0400 2012
irb(main):005:0> end_date = Time.parse("March 23, 2012 5:00 PM")
=> Fri Mar 23 17:00:00 -0400 2012
irb(main):006:0> (start_date..end_date).step(15 * 60) do |date_time|
irb(main):007:1* puts date_time
irb(main):008:1> end
Mon Mar 19 09:00:00 -0400 2012
Mon Mar 19 09:15:00 -0400 2012
Mon Mar 19 09:30:00 -0400 2012
Mon Mar 19 09:45:00 -0400 2012
Mon Mar 19 10:00:00 -0400 2012
Mon Mar 19 10:15:00 -0400 2012
Mon Mar 19 10:30:00 -0400 2012
.
.
.
Fri Mar 23 15:45:00 -0400 2012
Fri Mar 23 16:00:00 -0400 2012
Fri Mar 23 16:15:00 -0400 2012
Fri Mar 23 16:30:00 -0400 2012
Fri Mar 23 16:45:00 -0400 2012
Fri Mar 23 17:00:00 -0400 2012
```

Comment: NoMethodError: undefined method `step' for 2012-03019 09:00:00 -0700:Time

Comment: or TypeError: can't iterate from Time with the range as receiver

Comment: What ruby are you using? A fresh build of ruby-1.9.3-p125 delivers  "TypeError: can't iterate from Time" in step running your code above.

Comment: Yeah, I get the same error.  I love the logic, but it breaks on my Macbook Air running Ruby 1.9.3.  It also breaks on my Windows machine running Ruby 1.9.2.  I'll play around with this on my Macbook Air with different versions of Ruby in RVM to see if I can get it working.  Thanks!

Comment: @MartinGraham I'm sorry this isn't working for you. I just ran it (the 1.9.3 edit above) on ruby 1.9.3, osx and it worked just fine.

Comment: @Kyle what does `ruby -v` say for the ruby which runs this code without error? Did you build it with rvm or ruby-build? what configuration options were used in the build?

Comment: @dbenhur running the 1.93 edit from my answer works on 1.9.3, not the first code I posted. `ruby -v ... ruby 1.9.3p125 (2012-02-16 revision 34643) [x86_64-darwin10.8.0]` installed with rvm with a simple `rvm install ruby-1.9.3` My first answer was runs on my home machine with `1.9.2p290` I believe. 100% sure it was 1.9.2

Comment: @MartinGraham you should be able to use my 1.9.3 edit above. It is almost the same code you provided. The only difference is the range check `(9..17) === curr_time.hour`

Answer (score 1):

I thought that #step would suit this just fine, then tried it and discovered that Ruby's Time objects don't respond to #step as Numerics do.

It's a nice idiom, so I mixed it in:

```
MIN = 60
HR  = 60 * MIN
DAY = 24 * HR

start_date = Time.mktime(2012,3,19,0,0,0)
end_date   = Time.mktime(2012,3,23,0,0,0)

start_time =  9 * HR
end_time   = 17 * HR
interval   = 15 * MIN

module TimeStep
  def step(end_time, incr)
    t = self
    while t <= end_time
      yield t
      t += incr
    end
  end
end

start_date.extend(TimeStep).step(end_date, DAY) do |day|
  first_time = day + start_time
  first_time.extend(TimeStep).step(day+end_time, interval) do |tick|
    # make record for tick, or just print it for this example
    puts tick
  end
end

# Outputs...
Mon Mar 19 09:00:00 -0700 2012
Mon Mar 19 09:15:00 -0700 2012
Mon Mar 19 09:30:00 -0700 2012
...
Fri Mar 23 16:45:00 -0700 2012
Fri Mar 23 17:00:00 -0700 2012
```

Comment: -1 monkey patching when you only need a few lines of code. Clever but Not recomended for a person new to ruby.

Comment: Yeah, this is a bit over my head, but it certainly worked when I ran it.  I still like the simplicity of the previous answer, but this gets me going for now.  Thanks for your help!

Comment: @MartinGraham [Object#extend](http://ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/Object.html#method-i-extend) mixes the named module into the object being extended so the module's instance methods are available as instance methods of the extended object